# Ruby Sinatra-settings undefined method when accessing config file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm developing a ruby website using sinatra/sinatra-settings, I'm getting the following error while trying to access the variables from `config.yml`.
My main application is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'sinatra/config_file'
require_relative 'web_data'


class Main < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::ConfigFile
  config_file 'config.yml'

  puts settings.inspect
  c = Marshal.load(File.read(settings.svp)) rescue WebData.new(0)

  get '/a/:name' do
     c.increment
     File.open(settings.svp, 'w') {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(c)) }
     "Hello, #{params[:name] ? params[:name] : 'world'}!"+c.getcount.to_s
  end

end
```

My `config.yaml` is:

```
svp: app/systemvalues
```

Error thrown is:

```
2016-01-13 15:35:17 - NoMethodError - undefined method `svp' for Main:Class:

/home/miguel/workspace/personal_website/app/app.rb:16:in `block in <class:Main>'
```

I've tried adding the register Sinatra::ConfigFile, to no avail.

Oh and puts settings.inspect prints out `Main` (the class name)

Comment: Is your config file called `config.yml` or `config.yaml`? What gets printed if you do `p settings` inside the `get` block?

Comment: Hi, `config.yml` and `p settings` prints 'Main'

Comment: On a side note, found a workaround: `config = YAML.load(File.read('config.yml'))` and `config['svp'] to access the yml parameter

Comment: `puts settings.inspect` will always be the class name where the config is loaded.  So `Main` is the expected result.  To check to see if your config file was actually loaded, try adding `puts settings.methods(false).inspect` right below the `config_file 'config.yml'` line.  If loaded properly, you should see `svp` methods in the results.  E.g., `[:app_file=, :app_file, :app_file?, :environments=, :environments, :environments?, :svp=, :svp, :svp?]`  My guess is that this is a relative path problem.  What command do you use to start your app?  What does `ls -1` in your app's root dir return?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your YAML file has the `svp` value set for the three basic environments of "development", "test", "production":

```
svp:
  development: app/development-values
  test: app/test-values
  production: app/production-values
```